# User can define the virtual address ignoring API?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory-address

It was strange to me when I saw this:

```
#define HI3518_IOCH1_PHYS 0x10000000 /* 0x1000_0000 ~ 0x1020_0000 */
#define HI3518_IOCH2_PHYS 0x20000000 /* 0x2000_0000 ~ 0x2020_0000 */
#define HI3518_IOCH1_SIZE 0x200000
#define HI3518_IOCH2_SIZE 0x700000

#define HI3518_IOCH1_VIRT 0xFE000000
#define HI3518_IOCH2_VIRT (HI3518_IOCH1_VIRT + HI3518_IOCH1_SIZE)
```

This is located at arch/arm/mach-hi3518/include/mach/io.h

The last 2 line puzzle me, is that mean user can determine the virtual address themselves, don't need to use APIs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "user" are you referring to?  This is kernel code, and the kernel decides what the virtual addresses for everything should be.

Comment: @Wyzard, thank you. But I guess this topic I made is stupid. Because I find this virtual address is mapped to elsewhere, although I didn't really know that address yet, but It's not a fault, only my poor knowledge.....